# How to bind "control b" (that is b pressed after control not with it) to buffer-menu?

Tags: key-bindings

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C b") 'buffer-menu)`

This obviously gives `Key sequence starts with non-prefix key`
But I don't know what I need to unset to make it work.

Comment: If you mean `C-b` in both the title and the question body, please edit it to say that. `C-b` is Control + `b`. `C b` is Shift + `c` followed by `b`.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a dash between "C b", unless that's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

> This obviously gives Key sequence starts with non-prefix key But I don't know what I need to unset to make it work.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> tells me:

```
C runs the command evil-change-line (found in evil-normal-state-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘evil-commands.el’.

It is bound to C.

(evil-change-line BEG END &optional TYPE REGISTER YANK-HANDLER)

Change to end of line.
```

That is the non-prefix binding for `C` which you would need to unset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I meant pressing `control` and then pressing `b`

Comment: In that case your problem is that you wrote `(kbd "C b")` when you should have written `(kbd "C-b")`

Comment: Oh, you want Ctrl to act like a regular key rather than a modifier key? Emacs doesn't recognise any input at all when you press a modifier key by itself, so you can't do that unless you make changes at the operating system level (i.e. outside of Emacs) to stop Ctrl from being a modifier. (Chances are that you don't want to do that, though.)